# Trying to delete admin account

Tags: user-account, administrator

I made an admin account that I don't need and it just clogs my storage.
I have tried making new admin accounts and attempting to delete that admin account while logged into the new one, but it's just greyed out and I can't interact with it at all. I don't want to delete my primary account (korgi) and I want to completely erase the other admin account (Guest). The image below shows my POV when trying to delete an admin account. I know the other account's password. Any help is appreciated.  [image: What my POV looks like]

Answer (score 4):

Well:

1. First of all you've got the "korgi" account highlighted, and that is the account you're using to access system preferences, so naturally, the "-" is grey.
2. The "Guest" admin account: is it perhaps still logged in?

Comment: Confirmed: you can't select an account that's currently logged in, it's greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Logging out of the "Guest" account let me delete it as user180941 and Tetsujin said. Thanks to everyone who contributed their time to this question!

Comment: The proper procedure is to accept user180941's answer. This will let others know an answer has be found for your question. You probably should should have posted an comment to user180941's answer, instead of posting your own answer. If you wish, you can eventually also accept your own answer.